# React Native ref to element is undefined in flatlist item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get a ref to an element whilst rendering a flatlist but the ref is coming back as undefined. 
See relevant code below:

Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.modalRef = createRef();
}
```

RenderItem:

```
_renderItem = ({ item }, context) => {
    const modalRef = context.modalRef.current; // Why is context.modalRef.current null?
    let onPress = () => alert("Something went wrong...");

    return (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <ListItemCard
                id={item.id}
                value="Some value.."
                onPress={onPress()}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Within Render function:

Modal on screen:

```
    <Modal
    ref={this.modalRef}
    text="Some text.."
    onPressClose={() =>
        this.modalRef.current.close()
    }
/>
```

Flatlist:

```
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={item => this._renderItem(item, this)}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modalRef.current` is `null` because the reference is assigned on mount of the `Modal` component. I assume that the component is not mounted at the time the `_renderItems` function is called.

I recommend that you use the ref inside a function that does not render a component, for example an event handler. There the `ref` variable should have a reference to the component.

Comment: The first bit makes sense, but are you able to expand on what you mean by the second paragraph?

Comment: @Imdad I updated my answer and tried to clear it up a little.

Comment: Got ya! That makes perfect sense. Thanks!